# Listview добавление картинок в список

Tags: android, listview, изображения

Как добавить картинки в листвью...
Добавление эллементов происходит при помощи эрейлиста, можно ли как нибудь извлечь позицию эллемента эрейлиста и рядом рисовать картинку?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно дописать адаптер. Он будет вызывать метод `getView`, где Вам нужно будет заполнить поля. В том числе, можно заполнить и картинку. Пример можно посмотреть [здесь](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/10/android-listview-example-with-image-and.html).

Comment: спасибо большое,а если разбить итемы по группам еще адаптер нужен?

Comment: можно сделать на базе [ExpandableListView](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/86-urok-45-spisok-derevo-expandablelistview.html)

Comment: вернулся к тому с чего и начинал, а можно их как нибудь совместить?)

Comment: ExpandableListView - это всего навсего просто более навороченный listview.

Но можно сделать и на базе ListView вот [статейка](http://cyrilmottier.com/2011/07/05/listview-tips-tricks-2-section-your-listview/). Фишка в том, что каждый элемент имеет заголовок, просто отображается он только для некоторых, что создает полную иллюзию.

Comment: большое спасибо вам за помощь =) в самом начале очень понравился этот компонент красивенький такой :D

Comment: извините уже не удобно обращаться, но не знаете ли вы почему при прокрутке експандбл становится белым?

Comment: возможно, [здесь](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/why-is-my-list-black-android.html) описана Ваша проблема.